# How to make UITableViewDataSource ask for cell height before each cellForRowAtIndexPath call?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I have many cells which contains several resizable UITextViews. I want to make dataSource to call heightForRowAtIndexPath before every cellForRowAtIndexPath call, not only when table is reloading data. In that case I could return fake heights on reloading, and I would not need to redraw ALL textViews all the time when updating (performance is very low when I need to redraw lets say 1000 textViews), but just in time, when these textViews are truly needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Yes Do it with `UITableViewDelegate` implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` Like

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row == 1) {
     return 90;
   }
   else{
     return 45;
    }
}
```

Comment: if my textViews would not be resizable, that would be great option, but in my case if I changed textView width in one cell, I need to do that with all cells textviews, because it should work like columns. So in this method I want to return fake height value (then I would not need to count cell height for not visible cells) and make to ask dataSource for height before calling cellForRowAtIndexPath and then return true counted value.

Comment: As i understand this you can make two `int variables` one for `Max Height` and 2nd for `Min Height` and check retrun it as According to cell index or the Array index like i also describe ?